# Disable assertions while testing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing

I want to test the contract of my API so if, for example, an object is created with some parameter to `nil` an assertion is raised, but if the assertions are disabled (Release config) it simply returns nil.

My test scheme has the build configuration to Debug, so in my API contract tests I check if the creation of an object with some parameters to nil returns a nil object. But the assertion of the constructor is raised before the `XCTAssertNil` is executed, so my test always fails.

Can I disable the assertions while testing? I tried to add `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` to the scheme arguments passed on launch but that doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried adding an argument to pass at launch, but also check for it in your code.. so at launch pass TESTS=1... in your code surround the assertions in an if statement and check for if(TESTS)...

Comment: @Jay, thanks, I didn't thought that but I prefer not to make this kind of things, if this can be achieved other way the better.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Solved, I added a new configuration, duplicated from Debug, called `Test`.

[image]

Then added `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1` in the build settings preprocessor macros.

[image]

Finally, change the test action in the test's scheme.

[image]

Now it works :)

Comment: You can also overwrite the assertion macros for your tests, e.g., letting them throw an exception and than test that an exception was raised.

Comment: I the case you run into an issue: Unable to load contents of file list: 'Test-input-files.xcfilelist'

here we go:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55505991/xcode-10-2-update-issue-build-system-error-1-unable-to-load-contents-of-file-l

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [your self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30103162/1327557), it is useful to create a configuration dedicated to unit testing

In Objective-C you'll need to play with `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` and the more recent `ENABLE_NS_ASSERTIONS` indeed.

For **Swift assertions**, I found out from [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/111158) it depends on the compiler optimization level you chosed.

With `-Onone` the assertions will be triggered, but not with `-O`

[image: SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL]