# Xcode 10.2 Update issue Build system error -1: Unable to load contents of file list: input/output xcfilelist

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcode10.2

After upgrading to Xcode 10.2 I am getting 2 errors

> :-1: Unable to load contents of file list: 'xxxxx/Pods/Target Support
>   Files/Pods-xxxx/Pods-xxxxx-frameworks-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist'
>   (in target 'xxxxx')
>
> :-1: Unable to load contents of file list: 'xxxxx/Pods/Target Support
>   Files/Pods-xxxxx/Pods-xxxxx-frameworks-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist'
>   (in target 'xxxxx')

I updated all my  pod and changed build system to "Legacy Build System"   but still getting the same build error

Comment: This is absolutely critical to me also. Any updates

Comment: If this is an old project try to change build system to Legacy from file->Workspace Settings.

Comment: Remove Podfile.lock. Then run command pod install

Answer (score 162, accepted):

I struggled with this for several hours today and this is what finally worked for me:

1. `sudo gem update cocoapods --pre`
2. `pod update`
3. clean
4. build

From what I've read, this is an issue with the new build process that is enabled by default in Xcode 10.2 though I've not found the workaround clearly documented anywhere yet. There may be a more elegant solution than what I described.

Comment: Cocoapods 1.7 has been changed to Xcode new build system

Comment: I have this issue, and that solution worked for my local machine, however, this is still happening on the CI build system, any ideas?

Comment: After running the above command I get. 
'Updating installed gems',
'Nothing to update'

Comment: How can i solve this in CI system? Azure pipeline.

Comment: @MKarimi in my case the issue was related to the configuration being passed to 'xcodebuild' command, it was overriding the one provided in scheme, either remove it or try to match with a valid one

Answer (score 109):

1. delete 'Pods/', 'Podfile.lock', 'yourappname.xcworkspace'
2. `pod deintegrate`
3. `pod install`

it's work for me

**I have encountered this problem every time, using the above method to solve, I do not know why, how to completely solve**

Comment: Tried all above things but only solution worked was this.  Thanks @symbool

Comment: Only this solution worked for me. Delete workspace - it's a necessary step.

Comment: I think the key is removing the Podfile.lock

Comment: It seems that if you've added new configurations, doing the above will add the matching input and output files needed by each configuration.

Comment: This worked for me. Just used the pod deintegrate and pod install. I had gotten the error after creating multiple schemes/environments

Comment: Worked for me as well

Comment: I'm encountering this issue in my Flutter app in Xcode. Do I run the pod command from the IOS root of my project?

Comment: Just when I think SO is on the ropes, I get reminded why it's so valuable. Thank you for helping solve this.

Answer (score 65):

To illustrate the answer of @nfranzmeier:

Go to your project:

- Select the right target
- Build Phases
- Unfold `[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks` script phase
- Remove the files under `Input Files Lists` and `Output Files Lists` sections by selecting each of them and clicking on the `-` button

And you're done!

[image: Input/Output Files Lists sections]

Comment: helped, it's the actual solution

Comment: Tried this on Xcode 11.4, Xcode spits "error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation." Running 'pod install' would just put the two file lists back in place.

Comment: Tried this on Xcode 12.4  
Diff: /Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
Diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.

Comment: This works for me on XCode 12.5. Also I removed the [CP] Copy Pods Resources

Comment: After trying the accepted solution I had no luck, this is what worked for me

Comment: what does this do ?

Comment: Tried all the above answers. But only this worked!!.THANK YOU

Comment: only what worked ????

Answer (score 32):

None of the solutions above worked for me. What did the trick was:

1. Go to Xcode > Project > Info > Configurations
2. Set the values for Debug > Pods-XXX.debug and Release = Pods-XXX.release

This solved the issue for me on Xcode 12.0 beta

Comment: this helped me - my project had "Release" renamed to "Release-External"

Comment: This was the only one worked for me, thanks :).

Comment: This is the actual solution for this issue, thanks @soCohesive

Comment: I spent hours working on this problem, and this was the only one that worked for me too !! THANKS !!!

Comment: Thanks, this is the only one which worked for me

Comment: I just wanted to ket you know you just saved me, AGAIN. I found this answer realizing I had upvoted it in the past but I don't remember any of it. But now it solved my problem yet again. I'm so happy

Answer (score 20):

This worked out for me:

cd ios && pod deintegrate

pod install

Then go ahead and rerun your project

Answer (score 18):

Just `pod install` fixes this.

You don't necessarily want to update your pods (especially if you have not locked in versions explicitly). We had this error after creating a new Scheme.

Answer (score 14):

This solved my problem:

```
Open **Terminal**
1) run -> pod deintegrate
2) run -> pod install

In **Xcode**
3) Click Product Menu
4) Keep Pressing Option Button
5) Click Clean Build Folder
6) Run
```

Answer (score 13):

I had changed the Run Configurations, from: `Debug` to `DEV`, but didn't change the Scheme:

On top left, select your project name, next to your device:

[image]

Then, select your project and click "Edit"

[image]

Last, change from `Debug` to your desired "Run configuration", in my case was `DEV`:

[image]

Do that, for every single one in the list on the left, but for `Profile`, leave that one as `Release` or your equivalent:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

In my case the error happened when archiving the app.

The cause was that the wrong build configuration was selected in the build scheme. This happened after introducing xcconfig-files for staging environment.

**How i fixed it:**

- select the build scheme in Xcode (next to the "play" button)
- select product -> scheme -> edit scheme
- check if the correct build scheme is selected

see here:
[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can just edit your xxxx.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj file and delete the offending lines xxxinput-files.xcfilelist and xxxoutput-files.xcfilelist from the inputFileListPaths() outputFileListPaths() so they're empty again and then save it and rebuild

Comment: I had to open the file with an external editor an search for it as on XCode it doesn't appear. Maybe the problem is that I'm using XCode 10 and 11 for different projects and maybe I opened the conflicting one with the wrong version.

Answer (score 7):

For me, this was caused because I was setting up a custom configuration (.xcconfig) file for different environments.
I wasn't importing the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-XXXXXX/Pods-XXXXXX.release.xcconfig` into my configuration file.

This guide helped me find the missing step.
https://thoughtbot.com/blog/let-s-setup-your-ios-environments

Thanks Patrick.

Comment: Thanks I have the same issue, different flavors. But it has been pretty hard to get to this point. Trying this solution now.

Comment: If you know, do let me know if it's possible to add dynamic value in #include so the same file can be used for debug and release. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

For myself it works like that:

For example app name is "xyz"

click xyz(top) -> project(xyz)-> info -> configuration -> Debug -> xyz -> "Select Pods-xyz.debug"

xcode-13 or above

Answer (score 3):

```
In my case 
 -> pod deintegrate
 -> pod clean 
 -> pod install 
 then rebuild the project works fine. 
 My XCode = 11.3.1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You've left three answers in this same form. It would be good to make clear how you are sure that "your case" is the same as the case presented in the question and to explain how these steps do what they do and why that solves the problem that was presented.

Comment: actual problem is accessing "frameworks-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist" file. all 3 problems indicate that they cannot access that file, that is why i have given the save answer.

Comment: My XCode version is 11.4.1 had the same issue, if my guess is correct a pod libraries are either missing or not matching the ones cloned from github and the above process is required to install and update the correct libraries and references. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

worked for me, env is Flutter 3.13.4 & Xcode 15.0

```
update ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig & Release.xcconfig

#include? "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug-dev.xcconfig"
#include? "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug-prod.xcconfig"

#include? "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release-dev.xcconfig"
#include? "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release-prod.xcconfig"
```

Comment: This was my issue also. I had updated the name of my scheme because I was using flutter flavors. I needed to update these files to support my flavor names. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`cd ios`

`rm Podfile.lock`

###### edit Podfile as below

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'
>> Uncommented and bumped the version to 10
```

`flutter clean`

`flutter pub get`

`pod repo update`

`pod update`

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps that worked for me:

1. In the terminal, inside of project document, type:

   pod update
2. If pod is not found, you should install Cocoapods:

   sudo gem install cocoapods
3. If it returns a ruby/gem error, you should install (or reinstall) Ruby:

   curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

   rvm install ruby-2.7.2

   sudo gem install cocoapods
4. Try to update pods again, and when it is finished, open .xcworkspace file.

Answer (score 1):

If still have this problem and using flutter, you should open Runner Info Tab (in  Xcode) set configuration file to None. then run pod deintegrate pod install.

Comment: He hasn't said that he is using flutter.

Answer (score 0):

For me (using Mac Mojave) using the above solutions didn't work..

I manage to successfully overcome this issue by installing RVM on my Mac via:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --auto-dotfiles --autolibs=enable --rails
```

As described [on this page](https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/).

And then re-install cocoapods via:

```
gem install cocoapods
```

And lastly run again:

```
pod install
```

I hope this helps someone who was stuck endlessly like me :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and do the below steps and now am able to make build successful

1. go to Project->Configurations and set the valid configuration file for configuration.
2. if you see already set correct valid configuration file then do  `pod install`
3. if you are not able see valid configuration file then `pod install` and Now you can see the valid configuration file just choose the right one now.

Note : I have this issue on Xcode 11.7

Answer (score 0):

I solve the cloud_firestore not found the issue as well by this after integrating a new version of that cloud_firestore.
(optional) update the podfile with the required version of cloud_firestore for fast compiling (saves 500k+ lines of execution).

delete 'Pods/', 'Podfile.lock', 'yourappname.xcworkspace'

pod deintegrate

pod install

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue with....

1. Go to your **Targets** in xcode
2. Go to **Build Phases**
3. Next go to **Run Script** and check it has any files in input file lists or output file lists
4. Now, Remove files **(input-files.xcfilelist / output-files.xcfilelist)** using symbol **-** from Input file Lists and Output file Lists respectively

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to go to your project directory.
2. Navigate to /ios
3. Remove Podfile.lock
4. Run project

Answer (score 0):

For me, using Flutter, I had recreated my MacOs app and hadn't yet run it.  Running the app adds the necessary files.

Answer (score 0):

update below files in your flutter project. go to ios > flutter >

**ios > flutter > Debug.xcconfig**

```
#include? "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig"
#include "Generated.xcconfig"
```

**ios > flutter > Release.xcconfig**

```
#include? "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig"
#include "Generated.xcconfig"
```

after trying all, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on computer with `MacMini M2 Chip` and this couple command solving this issue for me:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
gem update --system
```

Then `pod deintegrate` start working and project was builded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

(2023) For thoose who use Flutter:

Digging deep, i noticed my installed dependencies required IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET set to 12.
Which caused the same terminal message at compile time like yours.

Obviously fixed by increasing the required version in ios/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist

*I posted my answer because it looks like Apple likes to produce useless Error Messages that people start coming back to this post and still answer to this (yet) 4 years old thread.

Answer (score -3):

Change build configuration from release mode to debug mode.