# error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-xx/Pods-xx-frameworks-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'xx')

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

XCode Version 10.2.1

> error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-SMarket/Pods-SMarket-frameworks-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'SMarket')
>
> error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-SMarket/Pods-SMarket-frameworks-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'SMarket')
>
> error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-SMarket/Pods-SMarket-resources-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'SMarket')
>
> error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-SMarket/Pods-SMarket-resources-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'SMarket')

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55521074/8078036), not working.

I tried to clean, rebuild the project, still failed.

No idea which part generates these errors, please comment if I need to show details of specific files.

My Target -> Build Phases:
[image]

`[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks`
[image]

`[CP] Copy Pods Resources`
[image]

Comment: have you added run script in build phase for any pod?

Comment: @MahendraGP no, I don't

Comment: @MahendraGP I have two scripts may be concerned with this issue: `[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks`, `[CP] Copy Pods Resources`. Even though I deleted these two scripts, they will still be generated automatically after I delete the `Pods` folder and `pod install` again. I updated my post for more details about this.

Answer (score 61):

```
pod deintegrate
```

then

```
pod update
```

Comment: How can I handle it in CI system in azure pipeline?

Comment: @MKarimi 
- script: |
    cd $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)
    pod deintegrate
    pod install
  displayName: 'Reset and Install CocoaPods'

Comment: aah man you saved me.... i got same with KMP

Answer (score 7):

I found out under `[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks` and `[CP] Copy Pods Resources`, there're input files and output files sections. Just deleted files in those sections, and it works.

But I still have no idea why this error is generated.

[image]

Comment: In which screen do you see it in Xcode? How to navigate there?

Comment: under Build Phases

Answer (score 2):

In my case:

```
pod deintegrate
pod clean
pod install
```

With rebuild, the project works.

My XCode version is `11.3.1`

Comment: "clean" command might not work with old CocoaPod. update your CocoaPod by "sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.9.1" command.

Comment: When I run `pod --version`, it outputs `1.9.1`. It seems I'm running the latest version.