# codemagic keep build with error: '.../Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Release-input-files.xcfilelist' `

Tags: flutter, continuous-integration, codemagic

PS: I can use Xcode to build the version successfully.

I got the similar error when use codemagic. [unable-to-load-contents-of-file-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55505991/xcode-10-2-update-issue-build-system-error-1-unable-to-load-contents-of-file-l).

[image]

After made the changed mentioned in the above link.

I got build error in codemagic, but didn't should any message releated to build error.

[image]

Comment: it's related to `pod`

Comment: And latest build have error of : `[!] The version of CocoaPods used to generate the lockfile (1.7.2) is higher than the version of the current executable (1.6.1). Incompatibility issues may arise`.

Comment: do you have custom script to update Cocoapods and execute `pod update`?

Comment: @MikhailTokarev , hi , this bug is caused by I didn't select latest Xcode(10.2) in codemagic setting.  After I change the Xcode version in codemagic setting. it's fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to update your pods to match the new version or downgrade pods with the following custom script:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e    # exit on first failed command
set -x  # print all executed commands to the terminal
yes | gem uninstall cocoapods -v 1.7.2 || true
gem install cocoapods -v 1.6.1
```

One tip to show more logs is to enter `-v` or `--verbose` to build arguments in the build section.

Comment: this bug is caused by I didn't select latest Xcode(10.2) in codemagic setting.