# No such module 'AcousticMobilePush' only on simulator - Kotlin multiplatform project

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, kotlin-multiplatform

Project is successfully compiling on arm64-physical device, but I get `No such module 'AcousticMobilePush'` on simulators, also project compiles for simulators for the other team members.

I use the pod like this on Podfile

```
  pod 'AcousticMobilePush', :git => 'https://github.com/Acoustic-Mobile-Push/ios.git', :commit => '35a71f6ed1646f987b925fe7bb2d999c74f7a635'
```

Repo link : https://github.com/Acoustic-Mobile-Push/iOS

I tried to

1. Reinstall/update/deintegrate pods
2. Cleaned the derived data & simulators
3. Update CocoaPods
4. Clone the project into new directory
5. Make sure that "Find Implicit Dependencies" is Checked on build menu
6. Make sure Framework Search Paths is correct
7. Clean XCode cache.
8. Make sure to open xcworkspace instead xcodeproj
9. Make target iOS level same as Podfile
10. Changed the commit: to branch:master on podfile.

When I select that Pod as Target `'AcousticMobilePush'`  and build and run on `Any iOS Device`

I get the error

```
Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/AcousticMobilePush/AcousticMobilePush-xcframeworks-input-files.xcfilelist'
```

Comment: Didn't any of this suggestion solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55505991/xcode-10-2-update-issue-build-system-error-1-unable-to-load-contents-of-file-l

Comment: No they didn't @shadowsheep

Comment: Hello @EmreAkcan, what is the status of this problem?

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev I can run the app on physical device, but simulator still doesn't work, I just reinstalled xcode but no luck

Comment: Can't see whether the following recommendation was applied:https://stackoverflow.com/a/55712251/11533773 Also, please tell what happens if you create a new project with this dependency, is this working fine?