# Unable to CI/CD my native iOS app on windows azure

Tags: ios, xcode, azure, continuous-integration, cicd

Kindly I currently trying to add native iOS app to Azure CI to automate ad-hoc builds.
My app contains different schemes and pods and it on bitbucket.
I tried many different approaches.

- Approach 1: [Using pre-defined steps as this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMTfw.png)

Adding ad-hoc distribution certificate and provisioning profile and pod install steps are succeeded and this error appears in xcode step.

```
❌  error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/GoogleAppMeasurement/GoogleAppMeasurement-xcframeworks-input-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'GoogleAppMeasurement' from project 'Pods')

❌  error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/GoogleAppMeasurement/GoogleAppMeasurement-xcframeworks-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'GoogleAppMeasurement' from project 'Pods')

❌  error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseAnalytics-xcframeworks-input-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'FirebaseAnalytics' from project 'Pods')

❌  error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseAnalytics-xcframeworks-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'FirebaseAnalytics' from project 'Pods')
```

I tried different solutions on internet

- [pod deintegrate and pod setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55505991/xcode-10-2-update-issue-build-system-error-1-unable-to-load-contents-of-file-l)
- [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQUYBTpbHxc)
- [This too](https://blackdroids.com/index.php/2019/12/09/xcode-update-issue-build-system-error-1-unable-to-load-contents-of-file-list-input-output-xcfilelist/)
- [Removing input and output file lists](https://github.com/rocketinsights/Unity-iOS/issues/1)

But no success.

- Approach 2: [Using only bash scripts as this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Izmvm.png)

Adding development certificate step is succeeded but it fails in adding ad-hoc distribution certificate with below error

```
/usr/local/bin/openssl pkcs12 -in /Users/runner/work/_temp/distribution.p12 -nokeys -passin pass:dist | /usr/local/bin/openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -subject -dates -nameopt utf8,sep_semi_plus_space

SHA1 Fingerprint=C2:63:96:49:77:19:4D:CA:CE:BC:5D:05:71:01:D3:B9:6D:FC:0F:54

subject=UID=W7667V95PF; CN=Apple Distribution: RIPPLE INNOVATIONS FOR DIGITAL SOLUTIONS (W7667V95PF); OU=W7667V95PF; O=RIPPLE INNOVATIONS FOR DIGITAL SOLUTIONS; C=EG

notBefore=Mar  7 14:18:31 2022 GMT

notAfter=Mar  7 14:18:30 2023 GMT

/usr/bin/security unlock-keychain -p *** /Users/runner/work/_temp/ios_signing_temp.keychain

/usr/bin/security import /Users/runner/work/_temp/distribution.p12 -P dist -A -t cert -f pkcs12 -k /Users/runner/work/_temp/ios_signing_temp.keychain

1 identity imported.

/usr/local/bin/openssl pkcs12 -in /Users/runner/work/_temp/distribution.p12 -nocerts -passin pass:dist -passout pass:dist | /usr/bin/grep friendlyName

##[error]Error: /usr/bin/grep failed with return code: 1

Finishing: Install an Apple certificate (Distribution)
```

And also as you can see no success.

Answer (score 0):

Finally and thank God I found the solution

It was an issue because I did schemes wrongly.

It passed when I re-did schemes again following the right steps in this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GrI9b9fDcys&t=404s)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).