# Xcode 15 - issue with POD copy resources

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcode15

based on this answer:

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56966495/4239205)

I tried to remove the input and output file in order to solve this issue

```
That command depends on command in Target 'MyTarget' (project 'MyProject'): script phase "[CP] Copy Pods Resources"
That command depends on command in Target 'MyTarget' (project 'MyProject'): script phase "[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks"
```

but it's only a temporary solution, when I do `pod install` the strings are recreated automatically.

How can I solve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the "[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks" and "[CP] Copy Pods Resources" scripts are automatically generated when you run the pod install command in CocoaPods. The "[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks" script is created when a framework needs to be embedded from the added Pod, while the "[CP] Copy Pods Resources" script is generated when there are resources in the added Pod.

If there are issues with input and output files, you can add install! 'cocoapods', :disable_input_output_paths => false in your Podfile.